# Getting MsalServiceException: 'AADSTS501461 when trying to access a Web API from a console app using Msal

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to call an Azure AD protected Web Api with the acceptMappedClaims=true in the manifest of the app registration.  I'm calling from a console app using ConfidentialClientApplication. Below is the error message.

Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'AADSTS501461: AcceptMappedClaims is only supported for a token audience matching the application GUID or an audience within the tenant's verified domains. Either change the resource identifier, or use an application-specific signing key.

Comment: I think this blog should help with this https://securecloud.blog/category/aad/acceptmappedclaims/

Comment: The issue was fixed by using a verified domain like https://myapi.{yourverifieddomain} in the identifierUris of the manifest. I was using api://0274.................... which was the default when exposing an api.

Comment: @Jelard , did you have to register myapi.{yourverifieddomain} somewhere? and how was the {yourverifieddomain} verified in the first place? I'm having the same issue as well even though I have updated my domain to be verified.

Comment: @soler Under the Custom Domain Tab in Azure AD there is a status whether its verified or not.

Comment: @JelardMacalino, tks for your input. I have finally solved it. Here is what worked for me. Under "App Registration" > "Branding", you would need to make sure that the publisher domain is "verified". Then, under Expose an API, make sure the Application Id URI is set to https://{the publisher domain}. One thing I noticed is that if your app publisher domain is XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com, simply setting the Application ID URI to https://XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com seems to work as well. if you have already set the Application ID URI, you can simply delete it and then set it again.

Comment: Now if you need to set your own domain, it looks like you can go to https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/DomainsListBlade and add or remove domains as needed. In my case, I have DNS access to MYDOMAIN.COM, so I created new domains such as MYAPP1.MYDOMAIN.COM under the DomainsListBlade, which I am then instructed to configure my DNS for the domain with the TXT or MX record. once that is done and the DNS propagated, MYAPP1.MYDOMAIN.COM is now usable as a publisher domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re planning to use **non-verified domain based identifier**, then you will get the error you provided.

Below is [example](https://securecloud.blog/category/api/jwt/) for the Manifest changes (`AcceptMappedClaims`, and verified domain matching URI)

```
 "id": "901e4433-88a9-4f76-84ca-ddb4ceac8703",
    "acceptMappedClaims": true,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "9bcda514-7e6a-4702-9a0a-735dfdf248fd",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2019-06-05T17:37:58Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "https://samajwt.dewi.red"
    ],
```

Comment: Are verified domain based identifier those domains that are added under custom domain in Azure AD?